# How to filter multicolumn mysql data and display on the webpage using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Recently i have asked same question but this is improved one.
i have some select options on my webpage and as someone selects option i want to get data from database for the same. i tried to do but i am geting data for only one select . what if i want to get data with combination of 3 select fields . how can i achieve this. please help !!!

here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Filter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="rooms"></div>

        <div class="container main-section" id="main">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="location">Location:</label>
                        <select name="location" id="location" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="candolim">Candolim</option>
                            <option value="calangute">Calangute</option>
                            <option value="baga">Baga</option>
                            <option value="anjuna">Anjuna</option>
                            <option value="morjim">Morjim</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="stay_type">Property Type:</label>
                        <select name="stay_type" id="stay_type" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="hotel">Hotel</option>
                            <option value="villa">Villa</option>
                            <option value="studio">Studio</option>
                            <option value="resort">Resort</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="room_type">Room Type:</label>
                        <select name="room_type" id="room_type" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                            <option value="deluxe">Deluxe</option>
                            <option value="suit">Suit</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group"><br>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-success">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="display">


        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my script --

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    getAllRooms();
    function getAllRooms(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{rooms:1},
            success:function(response){
                $('.display').html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#location').change(function(){
        var location = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data:{location:location},
            success:function(response){
                $('.display').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and finally here is my action.php

```
  <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','cms_user','12345','rooms');


if (isset($_POST['rooms']) || isset($_POST['location'])){
    if (isset($_POST['rooms'])){
        $query_all = "SELECT * FROM rooms ORDER BY rand() ";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['location'])){
        $location = $_POST['location'];
        $query_all = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE location = '$location' ORDER BY rand() ";
    }

    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn,$query_all);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run)){
            $room_id = $row['id'];
            $room_name = $row['name'];
            $location = $row['location'];
            $stay_type = $row['stay_type'];
            $room_type = ucfirst($row['room_type']);
            $image = $row['image'];
            $price = $row['price'];

            echo "
            <div class='container rooms'>
            <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
            <img src='img/$image' alt='room' width='100%'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <h2>$room_name</h2>
            <p>$stay_type</p>
            <h4 class='text-success'>$location</h4>

        </div>
        <div class='col-md-2'>
           <br><br><br><br>
            <h4 class='text-primary'>$room_type</h4>
            <h4>Rs : $price </h4>
           <a href='#'><input type='submit' name='book' value='Book Now' class='btn btn-success'></a>
        </div>
            </div></div>
            ";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<center><h3>No Properties available</h3></center>";
    }

} 


?>
```

Thanks !

Comment: why not use an html form and serialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jquery, you should have a .change function for all 3 select boxes - when any of the select boxes change, grab and send all 3 values to your php page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getRooms();
    function getRooms(){
        var location  = $('#location').val();
        var stay_type = $('#stay_type').val();
        var room_type = $('#room_type').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'action.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                "location"  : location,
                "stay_type" : stay_type,
                "room_type" : room_type,
            },
            success:function(response){
                $('.display').html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#location').change(function(){
        getRooms();
    }

    $('#room_type').change(function(){
        getRooms();
    }

    $('#stay_type').change(function(){
        getRooms();
    }
});
```

In your php page, get the value of all 3 possible post variables and start building your query based on those values. It helps to split up the sql statement into parts and then just combine them at the very end.

```
# setting parameters from the post
$room_type = isset($_POST['room_type']) ? $_POST['room_type'] : '';
$location  = isset($_POST['location'])  ? $_POST['location']  : '';
$stay_type = isset($_POST['stay_type']) ? $_POST['stay_type'] : '';

# defaults
$select = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
$where  = " WHERE 1 = 1"; # to have a default where that is always true
$order_by = " ORDER BY rand()"; # you can always change the order by this way

if ($room_type != '') {
    $where .= " AND room_type = '$room_type'";
}

if ($location != '') {
    $where .= " AND location = '$location'";
}

if ($stay_type != '') {
    $where .= " AND stay_type = '$stay_type'";
}

$sql = $select . $where . $order_by;

/* execute query using the $sql string and output results here */
```

This will also not require you to set a rooms value since it will still execute a query for all items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want PHP to treat $_GET/$_POST['select2'] as an array of options just add square brackets to the name of the select element like this:

Then you can access the array in your PHP script

```
 <?php
 header("Content-Type: text/plain");

 foreach ($_GET['select2'] as $selectedOption)
 echo $selectedOption."\n";
```

$_GET may be substituted by $_POST depending on the